# Add Cookie with the "Remember me" button JSF

Tags: jsf, checkbox, managed-bean

I have a little problem with my authentication application, I want to add the user's cookies only when he check the box "remember me", I work with JSF and Managedbean to do this .. the problem is that even if I check the box it returns me a false and does not change the status of the checkbox in true and does not reach the condition where I put inside my instantiation of the Cookie, below my source code and thank you.

Form :

```
<h:form class="login" id="formuLogin">
      
              
                    <h:inputText id="loginChasseur" placeholder="Username" value="#{chasseur_loginBean.login_chasseur}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['login.loginChasseur']}"></h:inputText>
                     
                    <h:message style="color:white;"  id="loginChasseurMessage" for="loginChasseur" errorClass="erreur" />
                     
                     
                    <h:inputSecret id="mdpChasseur" placeholder="Password" value="#{chasseur_loginBean.password_chasseur}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['login.mdpChasseur']}"></h:inputSecret>
                     
                    <h:message style="color:white;" id="mdpChasseurMessage" for="mdpChasseur" errorClass="erreur" />
                    
                    
                    <h:messages globalOnly="true" infoClass="info" />
                    
                    <h:commandButton action="#{chasseur_loginBean.validateUsernamePassword}" value="Connexion" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"></h:commandButton>
                     
                    <div class="remember-forgot">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="{chasseur_loginBean.remembre}"/>  Se souvenir de moi
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 forgot-pass-content">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="forgot-pass">Mot de passe oublié?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 
                </h:form>
```

My managed bean :

```
 @ManagedBean(name="chasseur_loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class Chasseur_loginBean implements Serializable{
 
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PrelevementBean.class);
     
    private String login_chasseur;
     
    private String password_chasseur;
     
    private String  statut_chasseur;
     
    private boolean remembre = false;
     
    private ChasseurLoginServices chasseurService = new ChasseurLoginServicesImpl();
     
 
     
    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean() {
             
        log.info("postconstruct chasseurLogin");
         
        System.out.println("la valeur de la checkbox post constract : "+remembre);<br>     
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
         
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
         
        if(cookies!=null) {
             
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                 
                if(cookie.getName().equals("loginChassCookie")) {
                    login_chasseur = cookie.getValue();
                }
                 
            }
        }
     
         
    }
     
    //validate login
     
        public String validateUsernamePassword() {
             
            boolean valid = chasseurService.checkuser(login_chasseur, password_chasseur);
             
            if (valid) {
                 
                System.out.println("la valeur de la checkbox 1 : "+remembre);
                 
                if(this.remembre) {
                     
                    System.out.println("la valeur de la checkbox 2 : "+remembre);
                 
                    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                     
                    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                     
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("loginChassCookie", login_chasseur);
                     
                    cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
                     
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                 
                }
                 
                System.out.println("la valeur de la checkbox 3 : "+remembre);
                 
                HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("loginChasseur", login_chasseur);
                 
                return "chasseurCorrect";
                 
            } else {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                                "Identifiant ou mot de passe incorrect",
                                ""));
                return "login";
            }
        }
 
 
 
 
         
     
    public String getLogin_chasseur() {
        return login_chasseur;
    }
 
 
 
    public void setLogin_chasseur(String login_chasseur) {
        this.login_chasseur = login_chasseur;
    }
 
 
 
    public String getPassword_chasseur() {
        return password_chasseur;
    }
 
 
 
    public void setPassword_chasseur(String password_chasseur) {
        this.password_chasseur = password_chasseur;
    }
 
 
 
    public String getStatut_chasseur() {
        return statut_chasseur;
    }
 
 
 
    public void setStatut_chasseur(String statut_chasseur) {
        this.statut_chasseur = statut_chasseur;
    }
 
 
    public boolean isRemembre() {
        return remembre;
    }
 
    public void setRemembre(boolean remembre) {
        this.remembre = remembre;
    }
 
     
     
     
}
```

Comment: May I suggest to try to use a full existing login framework instead of trying to develop your own. There are too many things you can do (unintentionally) wrong that create a security risk. And effectively, if I read it correctly) your whole question is not cookie related but the fact that the value of the checkbox is not passed on correctly. Please improve your question and your title

Comment: Yes it s about the checkbox , it s always false when i check it , so i just want to setCookie when the checkbox is true

Comment: Yes but what you **want** is not where your **problem** is... If you focus, you can remove 50-70% of the code in your question and it would still fail and have the same issue. Much easier for us to focus then. Please create a [mcve]. The cause is as far as I can see not visible from what you posted